# Get file from Google Drive based of Google Form info submission

Tags: google-apps-script

I have created a Google Form containing two fields (First Name, Last Name)
I have PDF files in Google Drive/specific folder, PDF files named as "First Name"+"Last Name"

I want to get PDF file from my Google Drive based on form submission and get the URL to be sent by email.

I need the way to get PDF file based on form user submission.

Answer (score 0):

I have written the below code which shall send the PDF as email attachment in place of the URL of PDF. I hope this code can help you. This code is a very basic code which can be further advanced as per your needs. Please let me know if you need any further help.

```
function pdfextractor() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Get active spreadsheet.
  var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
  var sheetName = ss.getRange("B" + lastrow).getValue() + " " + ss.getRange("C" + lastrow).getValue(); //considering format 'FirstName LastName' stored in column B & C of spreasheet generated by submission of google forms.  
  var pdfName = sheetName + ".pdf";
  ss.getRange("D" + lastrow).setValue(pdfName);
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(pdfName);
  var body = "This is a test email";
  var subject = "PDF File "
  var email = "admin@gmail.com"
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    var file = files.next();
  }
  GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
    attachments: [file]
  });

}
```

You can also change the email of each mail you want to send if stored with the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to create [trigger that fires when the form is submitted](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#application_triggers). Based on this event, you can [get the responses from the form submission](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/item-response), use them to [search the file in Drive](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams) and send it attached to an email.

Here's an example that you can adapt to build what you need:

```
function onSubmit(e) {
  // Get submitted responses
  let itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  
  // Get form answers (assume the form has three question in this order: First Name, Last Name, Email)
  let firstName = itemResponses[0].getResponse();
  let lastName = itemResponses[1].getResponse();
  let email = itemResponses[2].getResponse();
  
  // Get file (first file found with specified name)
  let searchResult = DriveApp.searchFiles(`title contains \'${firstName+lastName}\'`);
  let respondentFile = searchResult.next();
  if (!respondentFile) throw 'File not found'; 
  
  // Send email with respondent's file
  MailApp.sendEmail(email, 'Your PDF File', 'Your PDF file is attached.', {
    name: 'Automatic Emailer Script',
    attachments: [respondentFile.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
  });
}
```